# how to trace shutdown event workflow on virtualbox

Tags: debian, systemd, virtualbox, acpi

Hi I've installed `debian 9` using virtualbox.
I customized kernel with ACPI support as below

```
Power management and ACPI options  --->
    [*] ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) Support  --->
        <M>   Button
```

When I click the close button of the virtualbox window with `send the shutdown signal` option, nothing happened

I make sure the kernel `button` module was inserted.

```
# lsmod | grep button
button                  5539  0
```

If I boot with debian's official kernel `Linux debian 4.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.2-2 (2017-01-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux` and  `send the shutdown signal` option, everything works fine. systemd start to shutdown just like `poweroff` command do.

I also tried to modify `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
HandlePowerKey=ignore
```

Then reboot and send the shutdown signal again, it was ignored as expected.

There is no `acpid` running to handle the event, and the systemd `logind.conf` take effect if I changed it, so the signal is only handled by systemd now.

How to make my customized recognize the shutdown signal?
(only `button` module was compiled and loaded for it now.)
Are there other kernel options needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it now, after tracing systemd source code `src/login/logind-button.c`
seems it is related to `/dev/input/`

so i enable it in kernel config, and it can shutdown normally now.

```
Device Drivers  --->
    Input device support  --->
         <M>   Event interface
```